# Wordpress WP_Query order can't be changed to ASC

Tags: php, wordpress

I have simple query.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => array($type),
    'nopaging ' => true,
    'posts_per_page' => $n,
    'offset' => $offset,
    'orderby' => $orderBy,
    'order' => $order
);

$postQuery = new WP_query($args);
```

$order comes as ASC or DESC, but it always ASC. I have found where it's rejecting, but can't understand why. In wp-includes/query.php (WP 4.1.1) on line 2383 there is an action that breaks my query parameters. (or as i understand sets them partly as global, but partly as my custom, because my post type is not changed)

```
    var_dump($this->query_vars['order']); // here it DESC (as i want)

    do_action_ref_array( 'pre_get_posts', array( &$this ) );

    var_dump($this->query_vars['order']); // And here it rejeced to ASC
```

Why does that happen?

Answer (score 0):

Got it, 
"Simple Custom Post Order" plugin adds it's own filters, that broke WP_query args passed by me. Have just tried to search what actions are in "pre_get_posts" hook, and found that plugins ads it's own logic, have switched it off, and everything is working.

So, if you have similar problems, check your plugins as well.